# Wrap new div around several elements (Mootools1.2)

Tags: mootools

I recently started working at a job where they use Mootools 1.2 for their site. I am doing some new objects for their inhouse CMS-system and have run into some problems.

The system puts out this code for an object.

```
<div class="object_start">Title</div>
<div class="normaltext">Blahahahahaha</div>
<div class="normaltext">More text</div>
<div class="singlebox">Some content</div>
<div class="object_end></div>
```

I need to wrap a div around this, .... through javascript.

Since this object should be able to be present more than once on the site I've started with something like

```
function apply_drop() {
  $$('.object_start').each(make_drop_tab_group_of_tab);
}

window.addEvent('domready', apply_drop);
```

to start going through each instance where an element with object_start is present.

Basically i would like to step through each element from object_start until it hits the div with class object_end and then wrap the new div around it but I just can't seem to get it right.

Anyone could give a small pointer how to easily do this? I really do not need to transform anything more, just add the wrapper.

/Björn

Answer (score 1):

The MooTools documentation is your friend. For this I'm using [`wraps()`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element%3awraps) and [`grab()`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element%3agrab):

```
function apply_drop() {
    var beginWrapping = false, wrapper;
    // iterate over all divs
    $$('div').each(function(item){
        // if .object_start, wrap it in a div with class .wrapper
        // and then start wrapping all elements until we hit
        // a div with class .object_end
        if (item.hasClass('object_start')){
            wrapper = new Element('div').addClass('wrapper').wraps(item);
            beginWrapping = true;
        } else if (beginWrapping) {
            wrapper.grab(item);
        }
        if (item.hasClass('object_end')) {
            beginWrapping = false;
        }
    });

}
window.addEvent('domready', apply_drop);
```

Answer (score 1):

in your domready:

```
document.getElements("div.object_start").each(function(el) {
    var wrapper = new Element("div", {
        "class": "wrap"
    }), end = false, next;

    while(!end) {
        next = el.getNext(); // siblings
        if (!next || next.hasClass("object_end")) end = true;
        if (next) next.inject(wrapper); // will work if no object_end found gracefully.
    }

    // done finding siblings, now replace the orig div.
    wrapper.wraps(el, "top");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w4brx/

Comment: I'm digging seeing different idioms for MooTools.